# How to make either of the fields mandatory in XML schema

Tags: asp.net, xml, xsd

I have a  schema as shown below ,i have a few questions regarding the schema

1.How to make `CourierNumber` or `WorkLocationCoordinate` mandatory.I have used one global type shown below

**EDIT**
Still no luck as Abel mentioned i modifed schema but it is failing.The input xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NOCPlantMapRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <NOCTypeID>0</NOCTypeID>
  <WorkLocation>
    <ParcelNumber>4545</ParcelNumber>
    <Roads>
      <WorkLocationRoad>
        <RoadName>dubai road</RoadName>
      </WorkLocationRoad>
    </Roads>
    <WorkArea>
      <WorkArea>
        <Coordinates>
          <WorkLocationCoordinate>
            <CoordinateX>56</CoordinateX>
            <CoordinateY>23</CoordinateY>
          </WorkLocationCoordinate>
        </Coordinates>
        <Communities />
      </WorkArea>
    </WorkArea>
  </WorkLocation>
</NOCPlantMapRequest>
```

And the schema is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="NOCPlantMapRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="NOCReference" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="NOCTypeID" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
        <xsd:element name="NOCTypeName" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="ApplicationName" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="Applicationtype" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="RelatedNOCRefNumber" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" />
        <xsd:element name="WorkLocation" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"  type="LocationType">
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:complexType name="LocationType">
    <xsd:choice>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="ParcelNumber" type="ParcelNumberType" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="WorkArea" type="WorkAreaType" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="ParcelNumberType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:complexType name="WorkAreaType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="WorkArea" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:complexType>
          <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="Coordinates" minOccurs="1" type="CoordinatesType" />
          </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
      </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="CoordinatesType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" type="WorkLocationCoordinateType"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
  <xsd:complexType name="WorkLocationCoordinateType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="CoordinateX" type="xsd:string" />
      <xsd:element name="CoordinateY" type="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

But i am getting error as shown below
Not valid.

```
Error - Line 6, 12: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 12; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Roads'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error - Line 19, 24: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 24; cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Communities'. No child element is expected at this point.
```

My main requirement is either `ParcelNumber` or `WorkLocationCoordinateType` should present,what went wrong?

Answer (score 5):

> 1.How to make CourierNumber or WorkLocationCoordinate mandatory.I have used one global type shown below

In your given code, these two definitions are not close together (one is at the 2nd child level, the other is deeply nested) so I have some trouble understanding what you mean by this.

It is not possible to have two elements at the same level (same XPath) with the same name but different types. If you try it, you would get (depending on your XSD parser):

```
E [Xerces] cos-element-consistent: Error for type 'LocationType'. 
Multiple elements with name 'WorkArea', with different types, appear in the model group.
```

If you can use XSD 1.1, you [can work around this by using assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620822/111575). Since the only information in `WorkArea` is the coordinates, I assume you mean to switch between either `CourierNumber` in first position, or `WorkArea` in second position, but not both (really, it would have helped to show an instance document with the variants you want).

> If so how to apply the type in element name CourierNumber and WorkLocationCoordinate since 'CourierNumber' already contains type xsd:unsignedShort

This is where your real issue lies. Since you do not use named types (everything is one big element with anonymous complex type definitions), you cannot reference those types. One solution is to repeat the definitions, but this can become tedious and has its limitations.

The solution I provide you below simply refactors your code into a "type first" approach. That is, instead of one big (hard to read) element definition, you get small chunks of named type definitions. Opinions may vary, but I believe this is more readable, and it's definitely more flexible. A [good introduction of this approach and what its drawbacks and features are can be found on XFront](http://www.xfront.com/ElementVersusType.html).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <!-- belonging to SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183835/how-to-make-either-of-the-fields-mandatory-in-xml-schema -->

    <xsd:complexType name="CoordinatesType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" type="WorkLocationCoordinateType"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="CourierNumberType">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:unsignedShort"/>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="WorkLocationCoordinateType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CoordinateX" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
            <xsd:element name="CoordinateY" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="WorkAreaType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="WorkArea">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="Coordinates" type="CoordinatesType" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="LocationType">
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CourierNumber" type="CourierNumberType" />
                <xsd:element name="Roads" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Roads" />
                <xsd:element name="WorkArea" type="WorkAreaType" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:element name="Request">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Location" type="LocationType" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This validates either this:

```
<Request>
    <Location>
        <CourierNumber>12</CourierNumber>
        <Roads></Roads>
    </Location>
</Request>
```

Or this:

```
<Request>
    <Location>
        <Roads></Roads>
        <WorkArea>
            <WorkArea>                
                <Coordinates>
                    <WorkLocationCoordinate>
                        <CoordinateX>34</CoordinateX>
                        <CoordinateY>66</CoordinateY>
                    </WorkLocationCoordinate>
                </Coordinates>
            </WorkArea>
        </WorkArea>
    </Location>
</Request>
```

Comment: i dont want CourierNumber to be replaced by coordinates rather it should be present in its own place ie here top place.So either CourierNumber at top place or Coordinates at bottom should present

Comment: @peter, sorry, that wasn't clear to me from your question, but the approach is the same. Let me have another look.

Comment: i am not sure same answer applies to those situation, does it?

Comment: @peter, I'm still guessing to what you are after. I have updated my answer with a _possible_ solution. If you need to variants of `WorkArea` (one with, one without coordinates), then you need to use XSD 1.1, or better yet, rename the element name, for instance, `WorkAreaNoCoords` or something. In XSD it is vital that every path to an element is unique, and one interpretation of your question is that it isn't. If I'm wrong, then please, update your question such that it reflects what you actually want.

Comment: still no luck , i edited my question. My main requirement is either ParcelNumber or WorkLocationCoordinateType should present,what went wrong?

Comment: @peter, you didn't do much wrong, you just haven't finished creating the types. The error merely says that the instance xml has elements that are not defined at that location. Open it in a graphical xsd editor and you should be able to spot the issue almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the definition of the "CourierNumber" element to include the required attribute. Update this code:

```
 <xsd:element name="CourierNumber" type="xs:string"/>
```

to this:

```
   <xsd:element name="CourierNumber">
   <xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:simpleContent>
    <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
    <xsd:attribute name="Option" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
    </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
```

Reference from [Element-Mandatory Attribute declaration in XSD Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690949/element-mandatory-attribute-declaration-in-xsd-schema)

```
       <xsd:element name="Coordinates"> 
        <xsd:complexType> 
          <xsd:sequence> 
            <xsd:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" 
             type="Test" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="99"
             />
            </xsd:sequence> 
        </xsd:complexType> 
       </xsd:element> 
      <xsd:complexType name="Test">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="CoordinateX" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
      <xsd:element name="CoordinateY" type="xsd:unsignedByte" />
         </xsd:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
```

If you define the type of your element inline you can't name it so remove   the `type="WorkLocationCoordinate"` attribute (and then the `name="WorkLocationCoordinate"` attribute as well).

If you want to use those attributes then you need to separate element and type definition e.g. `<xsl:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" type="WorkLocationCoordinate"/>` and `<xsl:complexType name="WorkLocationCoordinate">...</xsl:complexType>`.

For more information on the error you mention in the comments, see [the type attribute cannot be present with either simpleType or complexType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200754/the-type-attribute-cannot-be-present-with-either-simpletype-or-complextype)

Comment: can you modify it based on my question because when i put type for WorkLocationCoordinate <xsd:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" type="Test"> i am getting error like The type attribute cannot be present with either simple type or complex type

Comment: try   <xsd:element name="WorkLocationCoordinate" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:Test">

Comment: same result  "attribute cannot be present with either simple type or complex type"

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32200754/the-type-attribute-cannot-be-present-with-either-simpletype-or-complextype

Comment: type and name will be same if you want to get rid off the error .For this you have to go through the link which i mentioned above

Comment: i have edit the answer. you can can also remove HeaderFields and paste the code of HeaderFields directly in  <xs:complexType name="WorkLocationCoordinate">

Comment: check the type as Test

Comment: or change <xsd:element name="CoordinateX" type="xsd:unsignedByte" /> to attribute name

Comment: Coordinates i aplyed ,nowHow to apply it for 'CourierNumber' since it already contains type

Comment: are you there ,if you can tell me how to apply type="Test" for CourierNumber since it already contains type="xsd:unsignedShort"

Comment: You suggest the OP to use an attribute, but how does his question relate to any of his elements having an attribute? His current design and approach is elements-only.